# Post JSON via PHP with Inbeaded html Code

Tags: php, html, json

Attempting to implement my json with php while adding a style with html and css. I attempted to use $output = "<'html code here'>" to display my styles and all. But I need it so I can have the json update a tile so you can scroll though while loading json. This is my first ever attempt at php.

And my codepen for the html:

```
    body {
      background-color: #2c3e50;
    }
    .row {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .tile {
      margin: 30px 30px;
      background-color: #ecf0f1;
      width: 25vw;
      height: 50vh;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .tile .price {
      background-color: #27ae60;
      width: 90px;
      height: 40px;
      float: right;
    }
    .tile .price h4 {
      color: #ecf0f1;
      position: relative;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .tile .image img {
      height: 30vh;
      width: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 10vh;
      align-content: center
    }
    .tile .title h6 {
      color: #95a5a6;
      text-align: left;
      display: block;
      padding-left: 10px;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    .tile .brand h6 {
      color: #95a5a6;
      text-align: left;
      display: block;
      padding-left: 10px;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    .tile .social-footer {
      display: block;
      height: 35px;
      width: auto;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: -4px;
      background-color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .tile .social-footer .trending h4 {
      color: #95a5a6;
      padding-top: -5px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      font-weight: 600;
      float: left;
    }
    .tile .social-footer .likes span {
      color: #7f8c8d;
      display: block;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: right;
      padding-top: 7px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .center-block {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    /*BOOTSTRAP CENTERING*/

    .container-fluid {
      height: 100%;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
      .tile {
        margin: 30px 30px;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
        width: 40vw;
        height: 80vh;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .tile .image img {
        height: 50vh;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 15vh;
        align-content: center
      }
      .tile .social-footer {
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 32px;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
      }
      .tile .social-footer .trending h4 {
        color: #95a5a6;
        padding-top: 7px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        float: left;
      }
      .tile .social-footer .likes span {
        color: #7f8c8d;
        display: block;
        font-size: 25px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-right: 30px;
      }
    }
    @media (max-width: 900px) {
      .row {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .tile {
        margin: 30px 30px;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
        width: 90vw;
        height: 90vh;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .tile .image img {
        height: 60vh;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 15vh;
        align-content: center
      }
      .tile .social-footer {
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 34px;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
      }
      .tile .social-footer .trending h4 {
        color: #95a5a6;
        padding-top: 7px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        float: left;
      }
      .tile .social-footer .likes span {
        color: #7f8c8d;
        display: block;
        font-size: 25px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-right: 30px;
      }
    }
    <container class="container-fluid">
      <!--START OF ROW-->
      <div class="row">

        <!--Product Start-->
        <div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="image">
            <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="title">
            <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="brand">
            <h6>By R+Co</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4-4">
            <div class="social-footer">
              <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="image">
                <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="brand">
                <h6>By R+Co</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4-4">
                <div class="social-footer">
                  <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                    <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="image">
                    <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="title">
                    <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="brand">
                    <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4-4">
                    <div class="social-footer">
                      <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                        </span>
                        <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
        <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="image">
                        <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="title">
                        <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="brand">
                        <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-4-4">
                        <div class="social-footer">
                          <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                            <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="image">
                            <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                          </div>
                          <div class="title">
                            <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="brand">
                            <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-4-4">
                            <div class="social-footer">
                              <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="image">
                                <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                              </div>
                              <div class="title">
                                <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                              </div>
                              <div class="brand">
                                <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-4-4">
                                <div class="social-footer">
                                  <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                    </span>
                                    <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
          <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="image">
                                    <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="title">
                                    <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="brand">
                                    <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-4-4">
                                    <div class="social-footer">
                                      <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                        <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="image">
                                        <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="title">
                                        <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="brand">
                                        <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-4-4">
                                        <div class="social-footer">
                                          <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                            <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="image">
                                            <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="title">
                                            <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="brand">
                                            <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-4-4">
                                            <div class="social-footer">
                                              <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                                </span>
                                                <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
         <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="image">
                                                <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="title">
                                                <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="brand">
                                                <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="col-4-4">
                                                <div class="social-footer">
                                                  <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                                    <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="image">
                                                    <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="title">
                                                    <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="brand">
                                                    <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="col-4-4">
                                                    <div class="social-footer">
                                                      <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                                        <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"><span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
                    <!--Product Start--><div class="col-4-4 tile">
          <div class="price">
            <h4>32.99</h4>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="image">
                                                        <img class="center-block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hcu8jcnmr/image/upload/c_fit,w_600,h_600/ichx6rlctigutk8qd0ky.jpg">
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="title">
                                                        <h6>Rockaway Salt Spray, 4.2 oz</h6>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="brand">
                                                        <h6>By R+Co</h6>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="col-4-4">
                                                        <div class="social-footer">
                                                          <div class="col-4-4 trending">
                                                            </span>
                                                            <h4>Trending<h4>
        </div>
            <div class="col-4-4 likes">
              <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--Product END-->
     </div><!--END OF ROW-->




            </container
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$output =  "<ul>";
foreach($json['curated'] as $curated){
$output .= "<h4>".$curated['category']."</h4>";
$output .= "<li>".$curated['title']."</li>";
$output .= "<h4>".$curated['price']."</h4>";
$output .= "<img class='center-block' src=".$curated['image'].">"; //posibly fix
$output .= "<h6>".$curated['brand']."</h6>";
$output .= "<h4>".$curated['trending']."</h4>";

}
$output .= "</ul>";
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Again posting my codepend so you can look at html: http://codepen.io/TwoKind/pen/rjvjox

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I basicly followed this tutorial after a hour and a half of googling.  http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-how-to-parse-json-file-with-php